# how to get particular key value from all the objects in a AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here is the code ,i just want to grab "url" key  and its value and store it in a variable 
i have tried several ways to segregate the key named url you can see that in my commented code

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "url",
  // data: data,
  // async: false,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=utf-8');
    }
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    // console.log(res);
    // re=JSON.stringify(res);
    re = $.parseJSON(res)
    console.log(re['url'])
    // console.log(re)
    // console.log(re["url"])
    // for(var url in re) {
    //   var value = objects[key];
    // }
    // console.log(Object.values('url'));
    // ok=Object.keys(re).map(key => re[url])
    // console.log(ok)
    // console.log(re)
    // $.each(re, function(key, value){
    //    console.log(key + value);
    // });
    // console.log(re[url])

    // const seg = re.find(item => item.key === "url");
    // const result=seg
    // console.log(result)
    // alert(res);
  }

});
```

Comment: So the URL you tried to access has a "post" at the end. It is also not HTTPS and lastly it likely does not allow your server to access it it seems, since we are getting CORS errors. Also IF it had worked, you would get JSON abck so not need to parse it

Comment: actually im getting the data from the server side  and i could convert it into json object my question is i want to get a particular key value pair from all the objects

Comment: What is the ajax response,is it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve CORS issues with your Django backend to get the response correctly. 
I see the response is of the following structure:

```
{
    "count": 51,
    "next": "http://scrapsh.herokuapp.com/api/post/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "asdas",
            "rate": 1,
            "author": "madhumani",
            "content": "asdad",
            "review": null,
            "url": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "okau",
            "rate": 1,
            "author": "madhumani",
            "content": "asdasd",
            "review": null,
            "url": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "DASS",
            "rate": 1,
            "author": "madhumani",
            "content": "sdfsdfs",
            "review": null,
            "url": null
        },
        ...
   ]
}
```

To get the url you can simply use `.map` on the `results` array:

```js
let response = {
  "count": 51,
  "next": "http://scrapsh.herokuapp.com/api/post/?page=2",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "asdas",
      "rate": 1,
      "author": "madhumani",
      "content": "asdad",
      "review": null,
      "url": "www.a.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "okau",
      "rate": 1,
      "author": "madhumani",
      "content": "asdasd",
      "review": null,
      "url": "www.b.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "DASS",
      "rate": 1,
      "author": "madhumani",
      "content": "sdfsdfs",
      "review": null,
      "url": "www.c.com"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(response.results.map(item => {
  return {
    "url": item.url
  }
}))
```